# Printed Page Table Headers Repeat only on Table without Page Break

Tags: css, reactjs, printing, chromium

Very difficult to explain so I have included an image:

[image]

(Apologies for red boxes of redacted information, this issue seems exclusive to this table containing protected content, am working on creating a minimal replication repository)

As said in the title, this only occurs when printing the page, in tables that are NOT page broken. Page broken tables work as expected.

Comment: Can you provide example code to reproduce the problem? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I am attempting but it's proving quite challenging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with Chrome 63.00 and has not yet been fixed. Until the next version it is recommended to use version 62.00